# How to disable server side validation for a certain field?

Tags: asp.net, server-side-validation

In my apsx page, I have a textbox that allows user input html tags. But it will get following validation error, "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client ...". I tried several ways to prevent it, none of them works except setting ValidateRequest to false. Now I am thinking is there any way I can disable server side validation for this textbox. I know in MVC there is couple of ways. But I am not using MVC. My page is just regular aspx, is there any way to do that?

I tried to set CausesValidation to False for my TextBox, didn't work, still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt244wbb.aspx

You can disable on a per control basis.

Comment: I tried on my textbox, I still getting that validation error if i put html tags. In addition, CauseValidation is set to false by default.